# Why does my char array not print anything?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

In c I am trying to assign a char array inside a struct with a user provided value, here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct person 
{
       char name[20];
       int age;
};

struct person *assign(char arr[], int age) 
{
       struct person *x = malloc(sizeof(struct person));

       x->name[20] = arr[20];
       x->age = 21;

       return x;
}


int main()
{

     char name[20] = "Arthur morgan";
     int age = 34;

     struct person* person1 = assign(name, age);

     printf("name: %s\n", person1->name);
     printf("age: %d\n", person1->age);


     return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the `name` prints nothing for some reason, the age however prints as expected.

Why is the `name` not printing correctly?

Comment: `x->name[20] = arr[20]` is accessing a single char out of bounds. You can't copy an entire array with an assignment statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x->name[20] = arr[20];
```

1. It does not copy the array
2. It copies 1 character and you are accessing array outside its bounds which is undefined behaviour (UB)
3. It is better to use objects not types in `sizeof`
4. Always check the result of `malloc`

You need to copy the string using `strcpy` function

```
struct person *assign(char arr[], int age) 
{
    struct person *x = malloc(sizeof(*x));
    if(x)
    {
        strcpy(x->name,arr);
        x->age = 21;
    }

    return x;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/vKddb4b9a